# Getting type error on .text() function

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I am trying to calculate something using the values from json file below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : 'outfitters.json',
            dataType : 'json',
            success : processTeam,
            error : function() {
                alert('error');
            }
        });

        $('#outfitters').submit(function(event) {
            var days = ('#days').text();
            var final_price = days * (("#length").val() + ("#material").val() + ("fibre").val() + ("#kevlar").val());

            console.log(final_price);
            $("#price").html(final_price);
        });


    });

    function processTeam(data) {
        var company = data.company;
        $("h1").html(company);

        var locations = '';
        for ( i = 0; i < data.locations.length; i++) {

            locations = data.locations[i].name;
            $("ul").append('<li>' + locations + '</li>').listview('refresh');

        }

        var feet_12 = data.twelve;
        $("#12feet").val(feet_12);

        var feet_14 = data.fourteen;
        $("#14feet").val(feet_14);

        var feet_16 = data.sixteen;
        $("#16feet").val(feet_16);

        var fibre = data.fibreglass;
        $("#fibre").val(fibre);

        var kevlar = data.kevlar;
        $("#kevlar").val(kevlar);

        var paddles = data.paddles;
        $("#paddles").val(paddles);

        var lifevest = data.paddles;
        $("#lifevest").val(lifevest);

    }
```

But I am getting `TypeError: "#days".text is not a function` when I click the submit button.
Doesn't look like a library problem as I am using the latest library. I am clueless as where I might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
$('#days').text();
```

Change everything from:

```
        var days = ('#days').text();
        var final_price = days * (("#length").val() + ("#material").val() + ("fibre").val() + ("#kevlar").val());
```

to

```
        var days = $('#days').text();
        var final_price = days * ($("#length").val() + $("#material").val() + $("#fibre").val() + $("#kevlar").val());
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to write :)

Comment: Moreover for some reason, final price is coming as zero :(

Comment: If you are doing math you will need to convert your values to correct number format: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: @Gajotres please do not point to w3schools - [w3fools](http://w3fools.com). Use MDN instead - [MDN - parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 0):

```
var days = ('#days').text();
```

Should be

```
var days = $('#days').text();
```